# Working with Constants (in Models)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants, rails-models

I am currently working on an app that stores grades in the users table like so (json encoded):

```
{"6":"6th Grade","7":"7th Grade","8":"8th Grade"}
```

There are constants setup in the Users Model for each grade span plus one to combine them all:

```
ELEMENTARY = %w(Kindergarten 1st\ Grade 2nd\ Grade 3rd\ Grade 4th\ Grade 5th\ Grade)
MIDDLE_SCHOOL = %w(6th\ Grade 7th\ Grade 8th\ Grade)
HIGH_SCHOOL = %w(9th\ Grade 10th\ Grade 11th\ Grade 12th\ Grade)
GRADES = ELEMENTARY + MIDDLE_SCHOOL + HIGH_SCHOOL
```

I am trying to figure out an elegant solution on parsing the JSON data stored in the users table to spit out which grade spans the user belongs too. So, if the user has the following:

```
{"0":"Kindergarten","1":"1st Grade","2":"2nd Grade","3":"3rd Grade","4":"4th Grade","5":"5th Grade", "6":"6th Grade", "9":"9th Grade"}
```

then the user is in a "general" grade span.

If the user has any grade selected in any of the constants then they are in that constants grade span. For example:

```
{"0":"Kindergarten"}
```

would put them in Elementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When that kind of situation comes up, instead of just trying to do a sort of "workaround", I prefer to re-think over the design. That logic, as the solution showed by **cmpolis** illustrates, is not that simple. So, why not create a new class to handle that? That would make it much easier to give maintenance, and also easier to read (and test - in case you write tests).

With that in mind I just refactored the solution posted by **cmpolis**, and I came up with something like:

```
class CheckGradeSpan
  def initialize(grades)
    @grades = JSON.parse(grades)
  end

  def is_elementary?
    (@grades.keys & ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]).length > 0
  end

  def is_middle_school?
    (@grades.keys & ["6", "7", "8"]).length > 0
  end

  def is_high_school?
    (@grades.keys & ["9", "10", "11", "12"]).length > 0
  end
end
```

That way you have a nice API to check for the user's grade spans:

```
grade_check = CheckGradeSpan.new('{"0":"Kindergarten","1":"1st Grade","2":"2nd Grade","3":"3rd Grade"}')
grade_check.is_elementary?
```

I think you can get the idea :)

Comment: Wow, never thought of it like that! Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for *elegance*, here is a decent solution:

```
data = JSON.parse({"0":"Kindergarten","1":"1st Grade","2":"2nd Grade","3":"3rd Grade"})
gradeSpans = []
gradeSpans << 'Elementary' if (data.keys & ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]).length > 0
gradeSpans << 'Middle' if (data.keys & ["6", "7", "8"]).length > 0
gradeSpans << 'High' if (data.keys & ["9", "10", "11", "12"]).length > 0
gradeSpans = 'General' if gradeSpans.length == 3
```